# 404 not found Heroku issue after a success deployment

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I've been trying to deploy this app for a while until I finally did it but now when access to Heroku's link of app told me 404 not found, I don't get why cause on my Heroku logs tell that all is right.

```
2022-01-27T19:50:34.203255+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-27 19:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-01-27T19:50:34.203567+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-27 19:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7631 (4)
2022-01-27T19:50:34.203630+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-27 19:50:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-01-27T19:50:34.207574+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-27 19:50:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-01-27T19:50:34.242787+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-27 19:50:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-01-27T19:50:34.741134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-27T19:50:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    return  render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/serviciosusa.html')
def usa_services():
    return render_template('serviciosusa.html')

@app.route('/areasdeservicio.html')
def areas_services():
    return render_template('areasdeservicio.html')

@app.route('/contacto.html')
def contact():
    return render_template('contacto.html')

@app.route('/taxes.html')
def taxes():
    return render_template('taxes.html')

@app.route('/visainversionista.html')
def inversionista():
    return render_template('visainversionista.html')

@app.route('/Migracion.html')
def migracion():
    return render_template('migracion.html')

@app.route('/realstare.html')
def realstare():
    return render_template('realstare.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to create a template folder in location where you have your app executed and place your html code there (eg. template/index.html)
2. You need to type full address into the url bar because you have `@app.route('/index.html')` so you would need to enter yourip:7631/index.html
3. Your code is good, it's just bad execution.

Comment: I did it and still not working. I added all files in a GitHub repository if you can see it ang let me know what a did wrong, I'll appreciate a lot.
https://github.com/ArturoMora21/internationalinmigracionflaskweb

Comment: @ArturoAlfredoMoraPerez Thank you for uploading GitHub repository... What you need to do is to change @app.route('/index.html') to @app.route('/') and build it... 
When you put @app.route('/index.html') your app listens on youraddress.example/index.html whereas whne you put there just@app.route ('/') it's gonna listen on youradrress.example/